# Help find alternative AC capacitor replacement for refrigerator compressor

Tags: voltage, power, capacitor, replacement, alternatives

My mini fridge is broken and doesn't blow cold air. I'm suspecting it's the capacitor because it tested bad and I don't hear the compressor humming when turned on (all fan runs). I wanna try replacing the cap first before the compressor. I'm having a hard time finding a capacitor with the exact same specification. I need help finding an alternative.

Here are the spec and numbers *shown* on the cap that was pulled out:

- 10µF±10%
- 250V~
- 220V~
- 2 leaded (both same length & color, black)
- No marking on the cap indicating polarity
- MkP 50/60 Hz 25/085/21
- SH 492819 11.03

I know I can replace a cap of the same type but with a higher voltage. What I don't know is the 220V. If I replace the cap with 400V for example, can I ignore the 220V part? Can the 400V take care of the 250V & the 220V? I don't see many caps that is 2 leaded and states two voltages. I usually see 3 leaded caps and states two different voltage.

What does the "25/085/21" mean?

Do I have to replace a cap that states two voltages?

Comment: _”No marking on the cap indicating polarity”_ Correct. You need bipolar/unpolarized capacitors for AC applications.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if a 400VAC cap will work, can I ignore the double voltage 220V?

Comment: Voltage rating-wise, higher voltage rating is always allowed. The double-cap part is hard to decipher.

Comment: Does the 220VAC mean it's the run voltage and the 250VAC mean it's the start voltage? Anything higher than 250VAC should cover both of these right?

Comment: No, 250 is just 240 + margin. Feel free to use even higher voltage rating on the capacitor as long as it still fits mechanically.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping this was the case too, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with a 10uF +/-10% (or +/-5% etc.) capacitor rated for 250VAC or better. Preferably one designed for motor use. The other markings don't matter much electrically.

For example, I see a 10uF +/-5% 370VAC cap for $4.99 at an industrial distributor. That would be a good replacement.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that yesterday but it's only reaching just less than 60°F at the highest setting over a 24hr-ish run. I replaced it with a 10µF±5%, 250VAC cap. It is possible it's not supply enough current?

Comment: Yes, it was a motor capacitor.